# drop lowest numbers from list in python

Tags: python

I want my  get_average function  to  take number list as the parameter, drops the lowest number from the list, and calculates the average number. The function returns the average number. I'm a begainner in python. I don't understand how can i Drop lowest number from the list. i'm really stuck.

my program so far -

```
def get_numbers():
    numbers = []
    num_to_get = int(input('How many numbers do you want to enter?'))
    while num_to_get > 0:
            num_to_get -= 1
            number = int(input('Enter a number: '))
            numbers.append(number)

    return numbers

def get_average(number_list, number):
    total = 0
    for number in number_list:
        total += number
    average = total/len(number_list)

    for i in range(len(number_list)):
        number_list[i] = 0
    number = 0

    return average

def show_average(value):
    print('Average:', value)

def main():
    numbers = get_numbers()
    print('Number List:', numbers)
    number = 123
    average = get_average(numbers, number)
    show_average(average)

main()
```

Comment: you can use `min(list_name)` to get the lowest number in the list

Comment: Please supply a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You posted a lot of code that does not relate to your problem.

Comment: Instead of `total = 0`, say `total = -min(number_list)`

Comment: i changed total = 0 to that. than when i enter 90 90 80 it gave me average of 60

Comment: Cool. now `average = total / (len(number_list) - 1)`

Comment: Thankssss John my code works now.

Comment: thankssss Now i understood how to drop lower num.

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the `min` and `remove` methods, in that order:

```
seq = [2, 5, 3, -2, 7, 0, 19]
seq.remove(min(seq))
print seq
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 3, 7, 0, 19]
```

`min` identifies the lowest element (-2).  `remove` then deletes the first occurrence of that value from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_average(number_list):
    numbers = list(number_list)
    #remove smallest number
    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    total = 0
    for number in numbers:
        total += number
    average = total/len(numbers)
    return average
```

Comment: what did i do wronge. when  i  run the code it says get_average() takes exactly 1 arguments (2 given) on line 32 in main.py

Comment: @Programmer1120 as you can see, David changed your method from accepting 2 arguments to a single argument.

Comment: yeah you only need one argument. You have for number in number_list:... you don't need "number" as an argument to your function. for number is number_list works without having number as an argument... it basically says "for each number in number_list, add that number to total".  Try get_average([0,1,2,15]). With 0 dropped... you're left with the list [1,2,15]. The sum of those number of 18. There are 3 numbers in the list so the average is 18/3 = 6. So get_average([0,1,2,15]) should return 6.